# Android how do to reflection in android.telecom.Call class

Tags: java, android, reflection

I want to block a phone call and i try using reflection android.telecom.Call class with following code but this class does not has constructor .

```
try {
        Class c = Class.forName("android.telecom.Call");
        Method m = c.getMethod("disconnect");
        m.setAccessible(true);

        Object o = m.invoke(c, new Object[] {});

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Exception of Reflection", e.getLocalizedMessage());
    }
```

Comment: What exception do you get. Please ask a question we can actually answer. See the FAQ https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You need to instantiate Class Call because you'll use the instance as a target for you [method invocation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#invoke(java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object...)).
2. The method [getMethod](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getMethod(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class...)) ignores non-public method. You should use [getDeclaredMethod](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredMethod(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class...)) to find your private method.

Your code may look like this:

```
try
{
    Class<?> c = Class.forName("android.telecom.Call");
    Object instance = c.newInstance();
    Method m = c.getDeclaredMethod("disconnect");
    m.setAccessible(true);
    m.invoke(instance, new Object[] {});
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Log.e("Exception of Reflection", e.getLocalizedMessage());
}
```

Comment: When i try this code it gives me an exception java.lang.InstantiationException: java.lang.Class<android.telecom.Call> has no zero argument constructor on line c.newInstance(). @Maaaatt

Comment: @AbhishekPanjabi this was a pseudo code to show a simple snippet for instantiating a class with reflection. I haven't tried it for this particular class Call and since it seems from your comment that it doesn't work, I would recommend looking at the documentation of this class to see how to instantiate it and if it's even possible (constructor may actually be private and there maybe no way for your to instantiate it without a Builder, Factory or any similar class).