# how to intantiate Call instance using reflection

Tags: android, reflection, call, dtmf

I am trying to send a DTMF tone in an incoming call. For that there is a method **playDtmfTone** in **android.telecom.Call**. As it is final class I am unable to create it's object directly.

That is why I am using reflection to get an object. but it throws an exception.
Here is my code:

```
try{
    Class<?> c = Class.forName("android.telecom.Call");
    Object instance = c.newInstance();
    Method m = c.getDeclaredMethod("playDtmfTone", char.class);
    m.setAccessible(true);
    m.invoke(instance, new Object[]{'1'});
}catch (Exception e){
    Log.d("Exception of Reflection", e.getLocalizedMessage());
}
```

I am getting following msg:

> Exception of Reflection: java.lang.Class has no zero argument constructor

I used this idea from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45523736/6229026).

I am not sure what is going wrong.

Answer (score 1):

According to android documentation, you can't directly create a Call Object. The only way to retrieve a call object is through InCallService's callback method onCallAdded(Call call) and through call object you can call playDtmfTone.

Comment: While this link may assist in your answer to the question, you can improve this answer by taking vital parts of the link and putting it into your answer, this makes sure your answer is still an answer if the link gets changed or removed :)